# WordPress table isn't being updated for some reason

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update the a field for my user with the code provided below according to http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#query_-_Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database

```
$wpdb->update($table, $data, $where);
```

Below you can see how I implemented it hoping it would work, but fails to do so. It just won't change the **email** for user **foobar** like it needs to.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update('wp_usermeta',
    array('email' => 'foo@bar.com'),
    array('user' => 'foobar')                               
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See if there's any error by first calling `$wpdb->show_errors();` and then `$wpdb->print_error();`.

Comment: Ty. This opened my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->usermeta,
    array(
        'meta_value' => 'foo@bar.com')
    ),
    array(
        'user' => 'foobar',
        'meta_key' => 'email'
    )
);
```